# JOOQ - Select count inside select query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a problem while converting the following statement into `jooq API`:

```sql
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, (SELECT count(*) FROM table2 where table2.col2 = t1.col1)
FROM table1 t1
```

I tried it with `DSL.count()` and `DSL.selectCount()` but I failed while searching a way to add the where clause to the count subquery.

The database is PostgreSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lukas suggestion to use [`DSL.field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Select-) is the better solution because it preserves the `<T>` type.

More typesafe version:

```
TableField<Table1Record, Long> col1 = TABLE1.COL1;
Field<Integer> count = DSL.field(DSL.selectCount().from(TABLE2).where(TABLE2.COL2.eq(col1)));
using(configuration).select(col1, count).from(TABLE1).fetch();
```

My first (less typesafe) solution:

```
TableField<Table1Record, Long> col1 = TABLE1.COL1;
Field count = DSL.selectCount().from(TABLE2).where(TABLE2.COL2.eq(col1)).asField("count");
using(configuration).select(col1, count).from(TABLE1).fetch();
```

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but it works. The generated query looks like my original query.

Comment: [`FieldLike.asField()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/FieldLike.html#asField--) is one way to do it. Another one would be to wrap the correlated subquery using [`DSL.field(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Select-), which preserves the `<T>` type and prevents using the rawtype.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using `DSL.field(...)`:

```
     Field<Integer> COUNT = DSL.field("COUNT(*) OVER ()", Integer.class);

     List<Map<String, Object>> records = DSL.select(ACCESSORY.ID,
                ACCESSORY.NAME,
                ACCESSORY.TYPE,
                ACCESSORY.PRICE,
                BRAND.NAME,
                COUNT.as("total"))
            .from(ACCESSORY)
            .innerJoin(BRAND).onKey()
            .fetchMaps();
```

The ResultSet will contain a column called `total` which will be treated as a type `java.lang.Integer`. This works with PostgreSQL 9.6.

A detailed description of `COUNT(*) OVER ()` can be found here: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48676/what-is-the-difference-between-count-and-count-over).